# Determinig when a Trig function $\cos(\sqrt{x+3})$ is negative

Tags: functions, trigonometry

So I have this trig. function:

$\cos(\sqrt{x+3})$

I want to know when this function will be negative.
I know that cos is negative in 2nd and 3rd quadrants but I'm not able to think in terms of quadrants here?
I would also like to know the range of this function and how its calculated for similar functions.

What I do know is that $x\geqslant-3$.

But that is not helping me find the range of this function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the range of $\cos(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, $\cos a$ is negative in the second and third quadrants, that is, for $\frac{\pi}{2}\lt a\lt\frac{3\pi}{2}$ (not including the endpoints because $\cos$ is zero there). In this case, your '$a$' is $\sqrt{x+3}$. So you need so solve the following:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\lt \sqrt{x+3}\lt\frac{3\pi}{2}$$ keeping in mind the restriction $x\ge-3$. To find the other values, use the fact that $\cos$ has period $2\pi$.

---

As for the range, the coefficient of the actual $\cos$ function in $\cos{\sqrt{x+3}}$ is just $1$, so the range is as normal, from $-1$ to $1$. The range would only change if a coefficient was added to $\cos$, such as $A\cos{\sqrt{x+3}}$, which would have a range from $-A$ to $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Baically, $cos(a)$ is positive for $0\le a\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}\le a\le 2\pi$ and negative otherwise,  Note that angles are mod $2\pi$

For your purpose compute $a=\sqrt{x+3}$ and see which interval it's in.